# django rest framework update method in serializer, instance is not saved immediately

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

The instance to be updated has `instance.email=abc@mail.com`.

email to be updated or changed to `xyz@mail.com`

`UserUpdateSerializer`'s update method.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        email_updated=False
        email = self.validated_data["email"]
        print(instance.email) #abc@email.com
        if email!=instance.email:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError("email is not available")
            else:
                email_updated=True
        instance.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
        instance.save() # instance is saved.
        print(instance.email) #xyz@email.com
        if email_updated:
            task_send_activation_mail.delay(instance.id)#this one here
        print(instance.email) #xyz@email.com
        return instance
```

I am using celery to send an email to the user when given a user_id to the method as:

```
from `celery` import shared_task

@shared_task
def send_activation_mail(user_id):
    from project.models import User
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    subject = 'Activate Your '+DOMAIN_SHORT_NAME+' Account'
    message = get_template('registration/account_activation_email.html').render({
        'domain_url': DOMAIN_URL,
        'domain': DOMAIN,
        'domain_short_name': DOMAIN_SHORT_NAME,
        'domain_full_name': DOMAIN_FULL_NAME,
        'domain_email': DOMAIN_EMAIL,
        'domain_support_email': DOMAIN_SUPPORT_EMAIL,
        'domain_support_url': DOMAIN_SUPPORT_URL,
        'mobile_support': MOBILE_SUPPORT,
        'user': user,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
        'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
    })
    user.email_user(subject, DOMAIN_FULL_NAME +' ', html_message=message)
    return user.email #"abc@email.com" is printed as celery output.
```

The instance is saved with `instance.save()`, where `email` is updated from `abc@mail.com` to `xyz@mail.com`and then the instance's id is passed as a parameter to a `shared_task` method to send a mail. But thought the email appears updated finally. The `User` instance obtained from the  `user_id` inside the `send_activation_mail(user_id):` appears to have not updated and the mail is sent to the previous `email`.

Comment: each time before printing email values use `instance.refresh_from_db()` because currently you are not checking if email is saved to database, you simply print cached email on model instance

Comment: @KamilNiski is correct. Even you can pass instance.email to the send_activation_mail() method and not to query on shared_task

Comment: @KamilNiski Yes. The instance appears to have not saved to database. How do I force it to save immediately after calling save? After the execution of the whole `update` method the instance is already saved. But not when `instance.save(0`

Comment: @Shameless Looks like your problem is not in the code you provided. I suspected the `instance.__dict__.update(**validated_data)` to cause the error. RIght now I would recommend pasting `settings.py` and using `ipdb` and manual debugging. Probably we don't have enough information to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `instance.save()` hasn't committed to the database yet. And before that the celery task `send_activation_mail.delay(instance.id)` has been called resulting in the getting the previous instance than the required updated instance.

So to overcome this we should be using `@transaction.atomic` and `transaction.on_commit` i.e,

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def myFunction():
    user = User.objects.get(pk=1).update(email="xyz@email.com")
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: my_task.delay(user.pk))
```

`@transaction.atomic` decorator will commit the transaction when the view returns, or roll back if the view raises an exception.

`transaction.on_commit` is a callback to launch a task once all transactions have been committed successfully.

> `on_commit` is available in Django 1.9 and above

Answer (score 0):

Is `validated_data` the same as `self.validated_data`?

Because i see that you use them exchangeable