# django and django rest framework instance.save() doesn't save to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an update method where immediately after `user.update()` I need to send an email where  I pass the user's id as a parameter to the `send_email_to(user_id)` method. But inside this method, I again get the `user` from the `user_id` passed and send an email. But it appears that the user is not updated yet to the database and results in sending mail to the previously saved `email`.

How to force to save to db immediately after `instance.save()` or `instance.update()`? I have tried `user.refresh_from_db()` and that clearly shows that the user is not updated yet.

Help me overcome this.

Comment: can you send some code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791225/django-rest-framework-update-method-in-serializer-instance-is-not-saved-immedia

Comment: is a transaction started in your database?

Comment: @vorujack Yes and the final result is: the email is updated. But not while getting user inside` send_email_to` method. I thought maybe it's problem with caching. But no. I used `user.refresh_fom_db()` and the result is the same.

Comment: you must send your email when db transaction completed